# Angular: how to launch a function clicking a span element

Tags: angular

I've bound a `click` event in the template to a `span` element and declared the function in the .ts file, however, the function does not get launched when the span is clicked.

This is the HTML:

```
 <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="date" formControlName="fechaDesde" name="fechaDesde" id="fechaDesde" type="date"
            class="form-control" >
        </div>

<span #dateFrom (click)="lanzaFecha(date)"  class="fa fa-search facturas col-sm-1"></span>
<span #dateTo (click)="lanzaFecha(date)"  class="fa fa-search facturas col-sm-1"></span>
```

And this is the function:

```
  lanzaFecha(fecha){

    if(fecha === 'dateFrom'){
      this.dateFrom.nativeElement.focus();
      alert(fecha)
    }

    else if(fecha === 'dateTo'){
      this.dateTo.nativeElement.focus();
      alert(fecha)
    }
  }
```

If I inspect the spans, they don't even have the `click` event attached in.

What causes this?

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a font awesome icon that launches the calendar.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax is wrong, pass string for dateFrom or dateTo, Modify span as:

```
<span #dateFrom (click)="lanzaFecha('dateFrom')"  class="fa fa-search facturas col-sm-1"></span>
<span #dateTo (click)="lanzaFecha('dateTo)"  class="fa fa-search facturas col-sm-1"></span>
```

Comment: You're right, I had a mistake there. However, the behavior is still the same. This is  what I get when I inspect the span in the dev toos:

<span _ngcontent-c8="" class="fa fa-search facturas col-sm-1 "></span>

No click event attached...

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to declare:

@ViewChild('dateFrom ') lupaDesde: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('dateTo ') lupaHasta: ElementRef;

...